# How can I monitor how many threads and memory usage in my JVM or Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, memory

I want to monitor the memory usage and threading, how can I do on the Eclipse or JVM? Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You can try `jvisualvm.exe` You can find it in jdk/bin directory. It's great tool.
Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) on the usage of it.

If you want to get the status in your java code, you can try JMX. Google the keywords "JMX Monitoring and Management".

Comment: Good answer. Make it better by adding reference the tools you have mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

[JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) provides a lot of useful information on threading and monitor contention and it has an eclipse plugin.

See these screen casts for monitor contention analysis:

- [Locking graphs in JProfiler](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2009/11/locking-graphs-in-jprofiler.html)
- [Monitor events versus locking situations](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2010/01/monitor-events-versus-locking.html)
- [Cumulating and filtering monitor events](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2010/02/cumulating-and-filtering-monitor-events.html)

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler

Answer (score 2):

in Eclipse, run the program in debug mode (this will also open the debug perspective). In that you can see how many threads are running.
The best tool for this could be an inbuilt profiler . 
I guess JVM has a profiling tool as well  or you can use third party profiling tool like 
JProfiler or yourkit.
http://www.yourkit.com/