# monitor java threads in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, view

how can you list or monitor threads used by a currently running project in eclipse? Is there a plugin because my eclipse doesn't seem to have such a view.

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731849/how-can-i-monitor-how-many-threads-and-memory-usage-in-my-jvm-or-eclipse

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you have started your application in debug mode. You can see the threads in the `Debug` view which is in the `Debug` perspective by default.

[image: Screeshot]

For detailed information you have to use [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/threads.html).